# How can the drop-down user menu be displayed above all div elements?

Tags: css, drupal

How can the drop-down user menu be displayed above all elements? In this case the menu (in Secondary Header ) slips under Page Title.

I'm using the "drop_down_login-7.x-1.3.tar" module

which css rule I must use?

Best Regards [See Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffY4z.jpg)

Comment: Please include your code here rather than tasking people with hunting down this Drupal module and reverse engineering it for you. You can just include the output from your page source for the applicable element.

Comment: That said, there is an easy way to bring content forward and that is with the `z-index` attribute. The default value for all elements is 0 so assigning a z-index of 1 might do the trick. If not, choose a higher number.

Comment: OK.. Sorry.. See the code ouput and demo block >>> http://www.giuliweb.com/img_demo_test/sdfsd12.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Did you try z-index? Find the z-index of the overlapping element and then add a higher index for your pop-up.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: The menu is positioned in a block and I don't know how to do it .. if it can be useful to place the screenshot with the page output >>> http://www.giuliweb.com/img_demo_test/sdfsd12.jpg ..Best Regards

Comment: Add a z-index to `#drop-down-login-wrapper` (currently only has a color attribute).

Answer (score 0):

You can use z-index in your css, but it must be higher than other divs which overlap on your dropdown.

Comment: The menu is positioned in a block and I don't know how to do it .. if it can be useful to place the screenshot with the page output >>> http://www.giuliweb.com/img_demo_test/sdfsd12.jpg ..Best Regards